# Can you vote to kick yourself in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When a vote is called to kick you, can you vote positive? (aka "yes" to kicking yourself)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to do that. Wouldn't it be faster and easier to just quit instead?

Comment: @Nolonar THere are some examples under my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. While in game open your developer console by pressing the ~ key on your keyboard. This is located on the top left hand side of your keyboard under the escape button. If this does not open the developer console you will need to enable it in the settings menu.
2. Type in status and press enter
3. Copy the 2 numbers next to your name.
4. Type callvote kick and then paste those numbers in. Then you will see the votekick box appear letting others know a votekick has started by you to kick you.

It should look like this:

```
\
status
### ## "NAME"
callvote kick ### ##
```

What's much more important is the above process works on a BOT. We've all had that moment where the bot survives with an AWP while everyone else is broke with 1150$. The bot can be kicked following the above process.

Comment: Not sure why in gods name anyone would perform a vote kick on themself, but +1 for finding a way to do that.

Comment: @Ramirez I've needed to do that once when my apartment started flooding during a comp game. Luckily I was playing with a friend and he explained the situation to everyone.

Comment: @Ramirez You don't want to get the cooldown, but god your team is cancer ... There has been games where I've been with a friend and the "Dude call votekick on me" has been mentioned between me and him.

Comment: Huh those are pretty legit reasons for vote kicking yourself, I guess now that I think about it I have had to have some vote kicks on myself when I have played FFXIV so I guess I have done it too.

Comment: @Ramirez By the way I've added an update to my answer which is mega-helpful much more often.

Comment: Just a note, this no longer works for BOTs in competitive matchmaking. They [patched](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2016/01/13531/) it in January 2016.

Comment: Either I do smth wrong or it doesn't work even in Casual.

Comment: @Ramirez I've only ever seen it used sarcastically, like someone messes up bad so they vote kick themselves.